# how can i add popup to flags in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I add `popup` to flag`s of highchart ? for example for this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/flags/
when I click on A flag the popup appear
How can i add that

```
 type: 'flags',
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 1, 14),
                title: 'A',
                text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add click events to your flag series, for example:

```
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                     alert("clicked!");   
                }
            }
        }
```

And example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5q3ufnse/). Just click on any `"B"` flag.

Comment: For me it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5q3ufnse/1/ just include Highslide and then use `click` event like in the demos.